# Event listener not firing?

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent, addeventlistener

I've tried to add two event listeners into my external script, both of which worked fine as event attributes attached to HTML elements.

The event listeners are:

```
parent.addEventListener("mousemove", where(event));
parent.addEventListener("mouseleave", reset(event));
```

The rest of the code can be seen here:
https://codepen.io/rowancavanagh/pen/NBmPGv
Or here in the snippet:

```js
window.onload = function() {
 var parent = document.querySelectorAll(".shadowed");
 var shadow = document.createElement("div");
 for (var i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
   parent[i].appendChild(shadow);
 }
 parent.addEventListener("mousemove", where(event));
 parent.addEventListener("mouseleave", reset(event));
}

function where(e) {
 var x = e.offsetX / e.target.offsetWidth * 10 - 5;
 var y = e.offsetY / e.target.offsetHeight * 10 - 5;
 e.target.querySelector('.shadowed div').style.transform = 'translateX(' + x + 'px) translateY(' + y + 'px)';
}

function reset(e) {
 e.target.querySelector('.shadowed div').style.transform = 'translateX(0px) translateY(0px)';
}
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
 height: 100%;
}

body {
 background-color: #eee;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.shadowed {
 position: relative;
 width: 400px;
 height: 240px;
 margin: 10px;
 background-color: #fff;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.shadowed div {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: 0 -10px -10px 0;
 width: calc(100% - 40px);
 height: calc(100% - 40px);
 background-color: #ddd;
 border-radius: 5px;
 z-index: -1;
 transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
 transition: transform .1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="shadowed"></div>
```

As you can see, they should be firing a couple of functions on mousemove and mouseleave, but aren't.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you can't attach a listener to an array of objects. (`querySelectorAll` returns an array with all elements found, even if is just one). You can move the attachment of the listener to inside the loop you have just above, using `parent[i].addEv...`

Comment: Didn't you see the error message `Uncaught TypeError: parent.addEventListener is not a function`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parent` is a NodeList as you used [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). You will need to use [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or a `for` loop to add event listeners to each of the elements selected by the query selector. If you only want to match the first element, you can use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and add the event listeners in the same way you have already done as it will return the first Element that matches the selector.

Change

```
window.onload = function() {
    var parent = document.querySelectorAll(".shadowed");
    var shadow = document.createElement("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
      parent[i].appendChild(shadow);
    }
    parent.addEventListener("mousemove", where(event));
    parent.addEventListener("mouseleave", reset(event));
}
```

To

```
window.onload = function() {
    var parent = document.querySelectorAll(".shadowed");
    var shadow = document.createElement("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
      parent[i].appendChild(shadow);
    }
    parent.forEach(function(item){
      item.addEventListener("mousemove", where);
      item.addEventListener("mouseleave", reset);
    });
}
```

Also, you only need to give the name of the function to the event listener; you do not need to invoke the function (passing in the event Object).

Change

```
parent.addEventListener("mousemove", where(event));
parent.addEventListener("mouseleave", reset(event));
```

To

```
parent.addEventListener("mousemove", where);
parent.addEventListener("mouseleave", reset);
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
 var parent = document.querySelectorAll(".shadowed");
 var shadow = document.createElement("div");
 for (var i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
   parent[i].appendChild(shadow);
 }
  parent.forEach(function(item){
    item.addEventListener("mousemove", where);
   item.addEventListener("mouseleave", reset);
  });
}

function where(e) {
 var x = e.offsetX / e.target.offsetWidth * 10 - 5;
 var y = e.offsetY / e.target.offsetHeight * 10 - 5;
 e.target.querySelector('.shadowed div').style.transform = 'translateX(' + x + 'px) translateY(' + y + 'px)';
}

function reset(e) {
 e.target.querySelector('.shadowed div').style.transform = 'translateX(0px) translateY(0px)';
}
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
 height: 100%;
}

body {
 background-color: #eee;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.shadowed {
 position: relative;
 width: 400px;
 height: 240px;
 margin: 10px;
 background-color: #fff;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.shadowed div {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: 0 -10px -10px 0;
 width: calc(100% - 40px);
 height: calc(100% - 40px);
 background-color: #ddd;
 border-radius: 5px;
 z-index: -1;
 transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
 transition: transform .1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="shadowed"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are invoking the function as soon as you are binding the event. The event handler needs a function reference.

```
parent.addEventListener("mousemove", where(event));
```

is supposed to be

```
parent.addEventListener("mousemove", where);
```

Also the `parent` var contains a live node list of all the elements with that particular class.
`addEventListener` is a method available for a specific element that needs to be bound separately.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var parent = document.querySelectorAll(".shadowed");
    var shadow = document.createElement("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
      parent[i].appendChild(shadow);
    }

    parent.forEach(function(elem) {
       elem.addEventListener("mousemove", where);
       elem.addEventListener("mouseleave", reset);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`parent` is the result of running `querySelectorAll`, so it will be an array of elements. You can move the event listeners into the loop so that all instances of `.shadowed` will listen for the events.

Another thing is the way you're passing the function to the event listener.
`parent.addEventListener("mousemove", where(event));` will set the result of the function call to the listener, you just want to pass the actual name of the function. The onload could look something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var parent = document.querySelectorAll(".shadowed");
    var shadow = document.createElement("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
      parent[i].appendChild(shadow);
      parent[i].addEventListener("mousemove", where);
      parent[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", reset);
    }
}
```

after those changes

Answer (score 1):

`parent` is an array and you can't add EventListeners to an array so you need to add the EventListener to each element of the array inside of the for loop

eg.:

```
for (var i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
  parent[i].appendChild(shadow);
  parent[i].addEventListener("mousemove", where(event));
  parent[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", reset(event));
}
```